# find.java:14: error: cannot find symbol JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

Basically I have a servlet named `find.java` created with Eclipse IDE.

The Problem is what compiling it I'm getting These errors:

```
D:\pack>javac find.java
find.java:4: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
                    ^
find.java:5: error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
                               ^
find.java:6: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
                         ^
find.java:7: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
                         ^
find.java:8: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
                         ^
find.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class find extends HttpServlet {
                          ^
  symbol: class HttpServlet
find.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
@WebServlet("/find")
 ^
  symbol: class WebServlet
find.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res
ponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
                             ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class find
find.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res
ponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
                                                         ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class find
find.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res
ponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
              ^
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class find
10 errors
```

As you might have noticed, Errors are throwing cause of java web-app builtin Variables such as `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse`

Based on my knowledge I would say This could be caused by not finding the libraries required to compile the file.

So I tried This:

```
D:\pack>set CLASSPATH="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib\*.jar":%CLASSPATH%
```

or

```
D:\pack>set CLASSPATH="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib\*":%CLASSPATH%
```

and

```
D:\pack>set CLASSPATH="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib\servlet-api.jar":%CLASSPATH%
```

Then `javac find.java`

But didn't worked and also my Environment variables are defined as:

User Variable for Nobody:

```
Variable Name: CLASS 
Variable Value: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\lib
```

System Variable:

```
Variable Name: jdk
Variable Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8

Variable Name: path
Variable Value: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin
```

FYI: I have Tested my servlet find.java at Eclipse IDE with sending and responding request which worked find but now I need to deploy it for to create .war file. But I'm getting these Error

Much Appreciations :)

Comment: @Jens Either I misunderstood you, or you are wrong. If we take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html -> "Class Path Wild Cards" section it explains `*` is "*considered equivalent to specifying a list of all of the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR*". I am not JEE dev so I am not sure about location of proper libraries, but maybe problem is that OP should use only `*` not `*.jar`.

Comment: @jens Okay I took a little long, But I did and still is not working

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found My answer, Thought it might help future generation.

So My Guess about it not finding the required libraries wore right. But other than using

```
set CLASSPATH="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib\*":%CLASSPATH%
```

I used:

```
javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib\*" find.java
```

Which here `-cp` tag stands for CLASSPATH Which compiles the program within the same directory as find.java is located.

Good Luck :)